# Card overlay moving other cards upon our grow

Tags: css

I have series of cards which contain an image an text. I want to append information to the active card when the user hovers on it. The information should overlay on the card below upon hover.

I tries to append the additional information to the active card upon hover and change it's z-index so it overlays on other cards. But some reason the the active card pushes the card in the current down instead of overlay.

Here is the JSFiddle I have created to illustrate the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/s9ou86a6/

I am surely not doing the display type right but not able to put fingure on the problem.

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
   width: 25%;
   background: #ddd;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 100px;
   z-index: 1;
}
.card: hover {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.info {
  min-height: 100px;
}
.info:hover + .extrainfo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.extrainfo {
  display: none;
}
```

Thank you for seeing the post. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this structure:

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 25%;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card: hover {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.info {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.extrainfo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.info:hover .extrainfo {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="info">
      Card Information
      <div class="extrainfo">
        Card Extra Information
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` to the `extrainfo` class and `position: relative` to the `.card` class so that the extra info will align to the card's bottom place by setting `bottom: 0;` to extrainfo class.

```
.card {
   position: relative;
}
.extrainfo {
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/s9ou86a6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

make this change and it will be over it.

```
.info {
```

min-height: 75px;
}

```
and for info:hover make z-index: 15;
```

Here is the change i just made. https://jsfiddle.net/TauseefJanjua/s9ou86a6/7/

Answer (score 0):

there's a few things i've noticed

1) Make sure that there isn't a space between : and hover.

2) You don't need to use the z-index. You could use absolute positioning and then use top/bottom/left/right to position your extra info wherever you want it to appear

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
   width: 25%;
   background: #ddd;
   margin: 10px;
   min-height: 100px;
   position:relative;
}

.card:hover > .extrainfo{
  display:block;
}
.info {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.extrainfo {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

Please see attached fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/s9ou86a6/2/